# Recurrence Relation(parameterized analysis)

Tags: algorithm

I got this equation
T(k,n)=6T(k-1,n-1)
k size of independent set
n is nbr of nodes in G.
G(V,E)

T(k,n)=6T(k-1,n-1)=6*6T(k-2,n-2)=...=6^k *T(0,n-1)
I am stuck here.

Algorithm

Consider vertex v.
By the argument preceing the question we assume that v has degree at most 5.
Let v_1= v and let v_2,...,v_6 denote v's neighbours.
We will write a simple branching algorithm as follows.
There are 6 cases.
In case i we assume that v_i belongs to the independent set.
In that case we remove v_i and all its neighbours and recursively search for a size-(k-1) indpendent set.
(There is no reason to consider case that none of the 6 vertices belongs to an independent set, since we might always add v_1 to such a solution.
Note that several of v_1's neighbours can belong to an independent set.)

They have said that it has sol 6^k*Poly(n)

Comment: You never said what T is measuring, which is always important. But if we assume you're using a RAM or similar model, then you're done.  T(0,n-1) = r where r is a constant amount of computation needed to check that k = 0.  I.e. it takes constant time to find that there is no need to do any more computation.

Comment: @Gene But then the sol should be only 6^k right?
since T(0,n-k) takes constant time.
But how come it became poly(n)

Comment: As I said,  you never said what you're counting with T. Probably they have T(k,n) = w + 6 T(k-1,n-1) where w is a constant amount of work. At any rate, constant _is_ Poly(n)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your definition, T(k,n) is the time it takes to find an independent set of size k in a graph with n nodes. For any constant c, T(c,n) is polynomial in n (e.g., try every subset of c nodes and check whether it is independent).

Comment: T(c,n) is polynomial in n ?
how many subset are there of c nodes?
n over c right?

Is T(0,n-1) the term that gives us poly(n)`??

Comment: When are we doing try every subset of c nodes and check whether it is independent.
We are only recursing in the equation.

Comment: My point is that for any constant c, T(c,n) = poly(n). 
The proof of that is an algorithm that solves Independent Set in polynomial time for any constant c.

Comment: The number of subsets of size c is bounded by n^c.

Comment: So the equation is not correct.
It should be T(k,n)=6T(k-1,n-1)*Poly(n)?
is n't nbr of subset of size c bounded by (n over c)?

Comment: When are we solving T(c,n) in poly time?
In the equation we are just creating a lot of sub problem. We stop when c=0.
do we solve in poly time when we assemble the solution?

Comment: The equation is correct. T(k,n)=6T(k-1,n-1)=6*6T(k-2,n-2)=...=6^k *T(0,n-1) = 6^k * poly(n), the last equality due to what I wrote above. 

(n over c) = n! / (c! * (n-c)!) < n * (n-1) * ... * (n-c+1) < n^c